# Sencha Touch and Admob without url

Tags: sencha-touch, admob

I have found some tutorials on the web on how to integrate admob with sencha. My problem is when you add a Site/App on admob, after selecting Smartphone Web for the ad type, one of the requirements is the Site URL. Now, the app I am creating is packed for android and ios but without a website counterpart.

How am I going to integrate admob to sencha without the needing to input the url of the app?  Can I just make up any url, but will this deliver/detect the ads?

many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can just leave that box empty, its your Publisher ID that's used to deliver the ads.